How to stabilise the BJT diff. pair feedback loop?
I need to remove the oscillation of feedback loop while fast response is maintained.
I have no problem to avoid the oscillation if 47 nF cap is placed across output but since I want to feed the input with 16-20 kHz triangle the maximum output capacity should be about 10 nF.
The simulation works well even with 10 nF but it oscillates in reality.
The problem can be slow response of PC817, however for 20 kHz signal without fast slopes like triangle is this optocoupler should be sufficient.
Is there some trick to easy compensate the phase is such a simple circuit?
Simulation:
(plotted Input and Output)(triangle signal on input)

Measurement of real circuit:
(plotted Input and Output)(constant DC signal on input)


Is the optocoupler with same ground on both sides just a simulation simplification (I do it all the time) or is the schematic as shown your actual situation?

This optocoupler will be connected as it is, because there will another optocoupler with leds driven parallel together (every led have own 220R) but second transistor isolated in another power supply.

Why are you making this out of discrete components? Why not use an IC instead? In other words, which create new problems that need solving, instead of using a part that has already solved them?

Quite often, where "reality" conflicts with SPICE simulations, the simulation omits critical electrical components. In your case, the voltage source V1 is perfectly stable, whereas it is likely connected with long wires (having inductance). Try adding a large bypass capacitor on your breadboard from +10V to the local ground.

Any kind of capacitive load like C10 is going to be problematic, regardless of frequency compensation. A low impedance push-pull stage after the opto-coupler's emitter follower could solve this, as long as you isolate C10 from feedback. Isolation is performed by R9 below, which is large compared with the buffer's output impedance:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
The "op-amp" may be unstable at unity gain, and the opto-coupler surely adds another pole to worry about, so frequency compensation is warranted, with or without C10. With only one gain stage following the long-tailed-pair, I don't see anywhere inside the "op-amp" to insert compensation that doesn't require a resistance in series with the non-inverting input. Here's how I would do that:

simulate this circuit
I've removed R1, since it serves no purpose except to cripple gain.
\$R_{COMP}\$ and \$C_{COMP}\$ produce a dominant pole, to obtain good phase margin when open-loop gain is 0dB. I don't think values are critical, since your desired closed loop gain is 1, and with the conservative values shown bandwidth should still be over 1MHz.

You don't need R1 or R7. R9,10 are also useless.
Bypass the optocoupler by connecting R3 to the output and see if oscillation stops. Likely your optocoupler is too slow (open base on NPN); find a different one.


the maximum output capacity should be about 10nF

The output capacitance is only adding phase lag into the feedback loop. The output capacitance should be zero. If you want to drive some output capacitance you'll need a follower stage just for driving that capacitance. The less capacitance the output sees, the better it is for stability.
The VAS (Q5) is heavily and variably loaded. Over the output voltage range you want, its gain will change a lot, and with it the stability. And the VAS has no compensation. You'll need an output stage after the VAS, it should be loaded with a current sink, and it needs compensation.
Overall, the thing is designed as if it was a comparator, and it works about just as bad as an LM311 would in the same application.

I want to feed the input with 16-20 kHz triangle

OK, so you need about 250kHz of large signal bandwidth on that thing, and a slew rate that matches that.  Consider LM358. It won't do a very good job here even if you'd use it in the best possible way. So you are trying to build a discrete op-amp with way better AC performance than a 358.
Look into discrete audio op-amps. They'll do what you want. You'll still need a driver stage for the LED. You'll probably need to run it those from a bit more than +10V unipolar as they are designed to run typically from ±15V.
There is a way of making a bespoke amplifier that will do this job well from 10V, but it may need a bit more than a diff pair + VAS=output stage.
You have also not shown the actual circuit you assembled. Edit the question and add the schematic of circuit you were testing.
